# Flow. How to specify the union type depending on the function argument

Tags: flowtype

Let's say we have two types and union of them:

```
type A = {tag: 'a'};
type B = {tag: 'b'};
type U = A | B;
```

And function, which returns A or B, depending on provided tag:

```
const getSpecificObj = (tag: string) => U;
```

How can I specify that returning type? So then I will be able to use it like:

```
const a: A = getSpecificObj('a');
```

P.S. Yes, I know that I can write the same function for every type or override. But maybe there are another ways. For example in TS I can write:

```
type Extract<A, T> = A extends { tag: T } ? A : never;
<T>(tag: T): Extract<U, T>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning a union of the types A and B, you need to parameterize the function `getSpecificObj` by the type of its argument, and then return an object which references that type parameter. Here's how I would do it:

```
type A = {tag: 'a'};
type B = {tag: 'b'};

function getSpecificObj<T : string>(tag: T) : { tag: T } {
  return { tag };
}

const a : A = getSpecificObj('a');
const b : B = getSpecificObj('b');
```

The annotation `<T : string>` on `getSpecificObj` makes sure the function isn't more general than you need, and will only accept strings as tags. You can think of this as moving the `string` annotation off of the `tag` parameter and into the generic *type* of the `tag` parameter.

You can view the example on the try-flow page [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN4YCGA5gFxgDkVjAvgNya4EBCpF1ekwBGbTqigBXAHYBjDAEs40sDTwYAyvlkKoC2QHlhAKwA8AFTAMAzhgBOC6TQB8ACkENzASisUwHsEtWClQwMDt1STsVcn9aMA5UVnRgYECACzxrAgwEODA8uwBrVFllWzAqX2IyNU1tXX0jY1dmRi9OMukK4V8+WvUtPB09QxNW0Q6UtPNM7P881QUANwI8Ozs4O2sAGkrrMAATLIUIw9LyjDBZav46oZGm8cZZds7LsDgTO8GG0ebXORWB0gA).

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgJIHIBuApmAIYAmZhZYAdoUgA4BOcDhTALgJaEDOYHOAIAWfYhwCebXqklswAQTABeMAG9UYASQDmALjC4SuADSawAYzjwmB3hyZcaO1AF8A3LKnEAQivXmHLoGuABGpuahcEyUtmD2js5unqhQAK40FtxwNGA6hBwAymwWXFBcFgDyoQBWADwAKmB2Dk46AHwAFEH6YA0AlM3q2r1NrgFaTAVpTLlqI2AebuiYfaK84ghCZHB8NLgcYFtMANakNBIAttGEqFY09qRDSqr5RSVlFdU1nUa4-Z57o9QkM-K8CsVCKVylVar9wgCgA

Comment: This is a different problem, unfortunately. In your modified version, you need a conditional inside of `getSpecificObj` to decide which additional field to add to the returned object. For this to work, Flow would need to be able to refine the type of a generic type parameter based on an `if` statement the same way it does for normal types. To my knowledge, there's no way to do this.

Comment: Basically you'd need something like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgJIHIBuApmAIYAmZhZYAdoUgA4BOcDhTALgJaEDOYHOAIAWfYhwCebXqklswAQTABeMAG9UYASQDmALjC4SuADSawAYzjwmB3hyZcaO1AF8A3LKnEAQivXmHLoGuABGpuahcEyUtmD2js5unqhQAK40FtxwNGA6hBwAymwWXFBcFgDyoQBWADwAKgZKAD5gPgB8ABRB+mAAJAAKLGycEg3ejSaGvbgd0wl2Dk46AJRgBg0BWmVgPboqyqpGuOsaWlpMBWlMuWraOtNWNktMYB7mrmCEMLzE5xcrhwbncHtMojF2K93p4tK43EA)